# Accessing the values of an element while parsing XML in Python

Tags: python, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<person>
  <first-name>First_Name</first-name>
  <last-name>Last_Name</last-name>
  <headline>Headline</headline>
  <location>
    <name>Some_city, STATE </name>
    <country>
      <code>us</code>
    </country>
  </location>
</person>
```

I'm trying to access First_Name, Last_Name, Headline and Some_city, STATE

So far I have:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(data)
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root:
  print child
```

Which prints out:

```
<Element 'first-name' at 0x110726b10>
<Element 'last-name' at 0x110726b50>
<Element 'headline' at 0x110726b90>
<Element 'location' at 0x110726bd0>
```

How can I access the value of 'first-name'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the [`.text`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.text) property:

```
for child in root:
    print child.text
```

Comment: is there a way to specifically say "Just give me 'first-name'?

Comment: @MorganAllen yup, `root[0].text`, for example.

Comment: @MorganAllen or, `root.findtext('first-name')`.

Comment: in the instance where the name is nested in location, how would I navigate to that?

Comment: @MorganAllen you can use an xpath expression: `print tree.findtext('.//location/name')`.